# История покупок Google Play Billing Library

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-billing

Есть ли возможность получить всю историю покупок пользователя приложения, а не только самые последние, возвращаемые методом `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()` ?
Под "историей" понимается выписка всех операций(транзакций) пользователя для всех платных объектов, предлагаемых приложением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В библиотеке судя по исходникам нет такой возможности. Вместо неё вам придётся напрямую использовать `Service` маркета для совершения запросов. Такие запросы вернут для истории часть совершённых покупок + токен для запроса не поместившихся в ответ транзакций и даст вам возможность запросить реально всю историю.

Вот дока к нужному методу: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference#getPurchaseHistory

Вот дока по самому механизму запроса через `Service` маркета: http://androiddoc.qiniudn.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Comment: Практически то, что надо - увидеть бы вот только как выглядит Bundle в ответ на getPurchaseHistory. Видимо, придется реализовать, чтобы это увидеть

Comment: @AseN, вроде по первой ссылке всё написано что там есть) А так да - проще увидеть, реализовав)

Comment: по ссылке есть описание полей, но напоминают они собой тот же ответ, который получается при queryPurchase* - а описание явно говорит, что "recent purchases", только эти вот вещи и смущают.

Comment: @AseN, там ещё есть `INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN` - его можно в вызов метода параметром передать и он выдаст следующую порцию данных. В либе такого в ответе нет и передать тоже нельзя)

Comment: при более внимательном изучении официальных исходников(в конкретно, метода queryPurchaseHistoryAsync) выяснилось, что метод вызывает все тот же getPurchaseHistory, который, в свою очередь, возвращает не всю историю операций для всех, а только самые последние("most recent"). Так что, видимо, получить историю покупок нельзя.

Comment: @AseN, не очень понял. Вы про библиотеку или про метод, вызываемый описанным мной способом через сервис? Насколько я понял доку - библиотека не может всё выдать, а через сервис можно всё получить.

Comment: Библиотечный метод производит описанный вызов с помощью сервиса. Результат этого вызова не содержит каких-либо предпосылок на полную историю - только самые последние покупки по каждому пункту.

Comment: @AseN, да, всё верно, в ответе либы нет токена и нет возможности его передать через либу. Если её не использовать, то можно получить и передавать токен непосредственно сервису. Так можно получить всю историю.

Comment: т.к либа полностью полагается на сервис биллинга, то можно предположить, что либо сервис в принципе не способен возвращать историю покупок, либо эта возможность имеется, но она что-то вроде "shadow api". В любом случае, был бы рад любым пруфам на возможность получения истории платежей какими бы то ни было методами. Есть вариант зареверсить коммуникацию сервиса с сервером но это требует времени, и не факт, что в конце ожидает успех.

Comment: @AseN, я не очень понимаю в чём у вас проблема. Если в доке написано, что метод вызванный через сервис даёт возможность увидеть всю историю, то с вероятностью 99% так и есть. Либа же не обязана использовать все возможности сервиса и, видимо, в данном случае их не использует. Например она, насколько я понял, не умеет заменять одну подписку на другую, хотя у сервиса такая возможность есть. Реверсить ничего не надо, надо лишь взять сервис и вызвать у него метод. Тогда всё станет ясно. Я сильно сомневаюсь что гугловая документация к такому важному инструменту будет врать.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, ткнуть меня носом в том место, где написано, что "даёт возможность увидеть всю историю"?

Comment: @AseN, я выше в комменте и в ответе писал, что там (в Bundle которым сервис отвечает) есть `INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN` ключ, по которому возвращается токен, который можно в запрос истории передать и тогда будет выдана следующая порция данных. В которой тоже будет такой токен.

Comment: Вот цитата из доки (первая ссылка в ответе): `String containing a continuation token to retrieve the next set of in-app products owned by the user. This is only set by the Google Play service if the number of products owned by the user is very large. When a continuation token is present in the response, you must make another call to getPurchases and pass in the continuation token that you received. The subsequent getPurchases call returns more purchases and possibly another continuation token.`

Comment: этот токен касается только списка товаров, которых в приложении может быть очень много. Подобное чтение методом "связного списка" спустя все недавние транзакции не начнет возвращать транзакции, предшествующие недавним.

Comment: @AseN, я несколько потерялся( Я правильно понял, что вы не верите тому что написано в доке? Т.е. вы считаете что метод не вернёт те данные которые описаны в доке? Или вы имеете в виду что он вернёт не те данные, которые вам нужны?

Comment: Доке я, конечно же, верю) Именно на нее и полагаюсь, когда говорю, что `INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN` - это про товары(добавляемые в консоли разработчика), а не про транзакции. Собственно, в доке так и написано: `retrieve the next set of in-app products owned by the user`

Comment: @AseN, кажется я понял. Да, судя по доке можно получить только факт совершения хотя бы одной транзакции по к-л товару. Сколько их было, судя по всему, узнать просто нельзя